# how make logstash data more clear?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I'm new in the elastic world
I have this configuration

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "C:/G_Dev/IdeaProjects/demo1/logs.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
         match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
       }

}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://********************************************:9243"]
    index => "myindex%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

in KIBANA I see this

** message:2022-03-17 17:24:50.431 INFO 21776 --- [http-nio-8081-exec-1] com.example.demo.Controller : can't find an employee, employee account id 5365647746374637**

how can I make this come like this
*error: can't find an employee, employee account id 5365647746374637*
instead of that long message
is that possible?

Comment: you'd have to use the grok filter to overwrite the message field with what you're interested in

Comment: I wnat that message field with its message become like this error:error: can't find an employee, employee account id 5365647746374637 which is my log https://stackoverflow.com/users/6113627/baudsp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6113627/baudsp and please one more question ,is it okay to download logstash config it with deployed elastic search credentials and then have logs,or I have to install logstash on ec2 ?